# Tensorflow install: No matching distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, installation

Already switched to Python 3.5 as Tensorflow only supports 3.5.

I'm trying to use the Tensorflow install guide with the following command:

```
  pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Which results in the following:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Running 32 bit python

Update:

Changed to 64-bit Python, tensorflow installed now. Would still like to know if 32 bit is even possible as I can't find anything about 32bit not working in the official Tensorflow guides.

Comment: I suspect only 64-bit is supported in official releases

Comment: I haven't seen this confirmed by Tensorflow anywhere. Is there an easy way to switch to 64-bit?

Comment: You have to build from source if you want 32-bit. I see from https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels that people have built 32-bit version successfully (for Raspberry Pi)

Answer (score 1):

Edit - I miss that it's 32 bit, my answer is for 64 bit.

I had similar problem on windows, I install python 3.5 but got the same error.
This is the steps I did to fix this issue:
first check that you have the exact same problem that I got, by checking your python version, by typing `python -V` in the command line (win key+R->cmd in windows).
if it's not 3.5, even though that you installed 3.5, then it can be the problem i faced with, so you need to change the environment variable in windows, this is done by going to :

```
Control Panel->System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables..
```

and then edit the `Path` value and change it to python 3.5 directory